# Putting one line per name using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql output that gives me different row for the same person based on their location. I wanted one line per person and three columns with a Y if they lived there.

```
Select name, Paris, London, NYC from location 

 Name      Paris      London        NYC
 John      y          
 John                 y    
 John                              y
```

I want this

```
Name       Paris        London      NYc
John        y            y           y
```

Comment: Will there be duplicate Johns in this table potentially? Would John potentially have 3 different primary keys but be the same person?

Comment: Just reread question, I misunderstood sorry!

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design.

Answer (score 1):

you can use max function :

```
select name, max(paris), max(london), max(nyc) from location
    group by name
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Subselects like:

```
Select name,
       (SELECT Paris FROM location WHERE name = a.name),
       (SELECT London FROM location WHERE name = a.name)
FROM location a
```

This way you make a Select in an Select, and link the subselect to the name of the overlaying select.

Some of the other users told you to use aggregations.
In the most database systems an aggregation query is less efficient than a subquery, so you should use aggregations with care.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name,
IF(SUM(IF(Paris='y',1,0)>0,'y','') as Paris,
IF(SUM(IF(London='y',1,0)>0,'y','') as London,
IF(SUM(IF(NYC='y',1,0)>0,'y','') as NYC
FROM location
GROUP BY name
```

Side-note, the database is not designed optimally! 3 tables with Name, Cities and Location with proper joins would be much more efficient.

Comment: Thank you very much